# Access generic variables using a function declaration with an external signature

Tags: typescript

For readability I like to declare my function signatures types separately from my function declaration.

So instead of:
`const foo = (a: string): boolean => true;`

I like to have:

```
type TFooFn = (a: string) => boolean;
const foo: TFooFn = (a) => true;
```

This works fine, but say I want to have a generic function that needs to use the generic variable inside the function body, so something like this:

```
const foo = <T extends Bar>(a: string): T => {
 const bar = createBar<T>();
 return bar;
}
```

How would I do this with an external function signature type?

I tried:

```
type TFooFn<T extends Bar> = (a: string) => T;
const foo: TFooFn<T> = (a) => {
 const bar = createBar<T>();
 return bar;
}
```

But that's not valid.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for this looks a bit different (and is also unintuitive in my opinion). I bet there's a good reason for this but I didn't look in the specs, you'd need to write the type and function declaration like this, as the generic belongs to the function rather than the function type (not all instances of this function type are bound to use the same generic type - they are specific to the different functions).
Here's the Code:

```
type TFooFn = <T extends Bar>(a: string) => T;

const foo: TFooFn = <T extends Bar>(a: string) => {
    const bar = createBar<T>();
    return bar;
}
```

Comment: It seems with that syntax I need to redefine the param types and output type. If I don't (re)define `a` as a string in the function declaration, typescript thinks 'a' is of type 'any'.  Which kind of defeats the purpose of having the external type in the first place.